# XPath find parent of a child element

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath

I have a structure such as this:

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="HighlightContainer">
    <div class="NodeTextHighlightContainer">
      <span class="TreeItemSelected">Products</span>
    </div>
    <button class="ContainerSelectedMenu" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because of how the DOM behaves and trying to stay dynamic, I can only target the span that contains text Products. using something like:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'Container')]/descendant::span[text() = 'Products']"));
```

However, I need to target the button where `class="ContainerSelectedMenu"` based of that span element, what is the best approach? Something like getting the parent div of the child of Container then finding the button element.

Comment: I am totally not experienced in this, but isn't `..` for selecting the parent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found different ways to do this by traversing back up and down which works fine, but my preference now is this approach:

```
xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'Container') and descendant::span[text() = 'Products']]//button";
```

Basically, you put the descendant with `text() = 'Products'` as part of the requirement for the `div` tag you really want, which is the parent. Then you can just search for the button easily with a `//button`, or `//button[@class='ContainerSelectedMenu']`

You actually don't need the `descendant` axes here, so it can be simplified a bit with this:

```
xpath = "//div[contains(@class, 'Container') and .//span[text() = 'Products']]//button";
```

In English...

- Find a `div` that
- **1.** has a `@class` that contains "Container" and
- **2.** has a descendant `span` element with the text `Products
- Find a descendant of that `div` that is a `button`

Comment: I think you need the `.` before the `//span` (so it would be `.//span`) so that it's starting at the current context.

Comment: @DanielHaley that sounds right to me, I'll make that edit, Thanks!

Comment: Great explanation, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to target the `span`, then go up to the ancestor `div`, and then back down to the element with the matching `class`...

```
//span[normalize-space()='Products']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'Container')]//*[contains(@class,'ContainerSelectedMenu')]
```

Another way is to target the `div`, then the `span`, then go up the two levels and then back down to the element with the matching `class`...

```
//div[contains(@class,'Container')]//span[normalize-space()='Products']/../../*[contains(@class,'ContainerSelectedMenu')]
```

Yet another way (similar to @mrfreester) is to match the `div`, test the `span`, and go directly to the element with the matching `class`...

```
//div[contains(@class, 'Container') and .//span[normalize-space()='Products']]//*[contains(@class,'ContainerSelectedMenu')]
```

All three of these match the `button`.